# How to Hide Server Scripts in Google App Maker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have client and server scripts, server scripts are called by client scripts and client scripts are called from UI elements. So, I need to hide server script methods to make my data more secure. How can I do that? In the documentation they say we can hide it by appending an underscore to the methods' name, this is called utility function but if we do that they can be called from only other server scripts instead of client scripts. In my case, they should be called from client script's methods.

Comment: The client has to communicate with the server if you want to run a server-side script. There is no way around that. But you should have some degree of security built in if the app is only accessible to users within your GSuite domain.

Comment: In addition to @DimuDesigns's answer, you can have more built in security at DB level, like which roles can perform which CRUD operations. Please provide a exact scenario which you want to prevent from happening via Hiding server scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a server side helper function to be called by the client side code and calls the server side private functions.

Bruce Mcpherson explains this on [Using promises with Google Apps Script](https://sites.google.com/a/mcpher.com/share/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/promisesandappsscript).

The client side code:

```
/**
 * @namespace Provoke
 * promise management for async calls
 */

var Provoke =(function (ns) {

  /**
  * run something asynchronously
  * @param {string} namespace the namespace (null for global)
  * @param {string} method the method or function to call
  * @param {...} the args
  * @return {Promise} a promise
  */
  ns.run = function (namespace,method) {
    
    // the args to the server function
    var runArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(2);
    console.log(runArgs);
    if (arguments.length<2) {
      throw new Error ('need at least a namespace and method');
    }

    // this will return a promise
    return new Promise(function ( resolve , reject ) {
      
      google.script.run
    
      .withFailureHandler (function(err) {
        reject (err);
      })
    
      .withSuccessHandler (function(result) {
        resolve (result);
      })
    
      .exposeRun (namespace,method,runArgs); 
    });
    
    
  };
  
  
  return ns;
  
})(Provoke || {});
```

The server side code:

```
/**
* used to expose memebers of a namespace
* @param {string} namespace name
* @param {method} method name
*/
function exposeRun (namespace, method , argArray ) {
  var func = (namespace ? this[namespace][method] : this[method])
  if (argArray && argArray.length) {
    return func.apply(this,argArray);
  }
  else {
    return func();
  }
}
```

The way to use the above on the client side is

```
Provoke.run ( 'Server', 'getData_' , 100)
.then (function (result) {
   '//do something with the result
},
function (err) {
  //do something with the error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use underscore symbol `_` in the end of a function name to make it private:

```javascript
function iAmPrivate_() {
  // safe to execute code
}

function iAmPublic() {
 // I am not safe, do security checks before execute
}
```

Read more:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions